# Can I adapt my 38mm auxillary lens microscope to use more widely available 42mm ones?

Tags: lens, adapter, leica, microscopy

I have a Bausch and Lomb/Leica StereoZoom 4 microscope that I would like to use for microsoldering and occastional photos. Unfortunately, it only has 10X eye pieces and no auxillary lenses or illumination.

[image]

The scope uses "standard" 38mm auxillary lenses. Finding a .5X lens isn't hard, but at over $100 a piece, I prefer not to remortgage my home. There are tons of inexpensive 42mm ones available, however, as they are more common.

[image]

Is it possible to buy an adapter that will allow me to use .5X lenses?

Comment: Although you plan to use the microscope for "occasional photos", I wonder if there is expertise here to adequately answer your question. You may be able to find a suitable "step up" ring, but it would alter the distances between optics, which would affect focusing. It seems you're also missing a stand.

Comment: I am a complete Newbie. I figured this is the best place to ask the question, since there is quite a bit of overlap between photography and microscopy.

Comment: It's fine to ask. But it might be one of those questions where no one here really knows the answer.